# PHP - FPDF | How to make a table from PHP variable containig HTML code using FPDF?

Tags: php, fpdf

So I have a `PHP` variable containing `HTML` code for my `table`. This is the content of my `PHP` variable :

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>fisrt column </th>
        <th>second column</th>                          
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="placeholderRow">     
        <td><input name="myname1" id="myId1" value="1" disabled="disabled" type="text"></td>
        <td><input name="myname2"  id="myId2" value="des" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I want to make a table from the content of this variable using `FPDF`, is it possible ? and How can it be done?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Have you read the docs for FPDF?

Comment: If you are referring to the content of this page http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/index.php , Yes I did and It is just a description of the FPDF functions, it is instructive but It didn't help me a lot

Comment: you should extend a class to do it, luckily there is an example of code from fpdf that you can try. please check take a  look at http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script41.php

Comment: because there was no answer to my question and I was in a hurry, I choose to work with tcpdf, I understood it better and got lots of help on it as well. thank you anyway @HilariusL.Doren